# 'AppAnalytics.logLogin' ('Future<Null> Function()') isn't a valid override of 'FirebaseAnalytics.logLogin' ('logLogin')

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-analytics

I recently updated my Flutter project libraries to latest and it started showing me some errors. Here is error:

```
'AppAnalytics.logLogin' ('Future<Null> Function()') isn't a valid override of 'FirebaseAnalytics.logLogin' ('logLogin').
```

Here are Firebase libraries version:

```
  firebase_analytics: ^5.0.2
  firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5
  firebase_database: ^3.0.7
  firebase_messaging: ^5.1.6
  firebase_storage: ^3.0.6
```

I have used this method as below:

```
  @override
  Future<Null> logLogin({String logLogin}) async {
    await _firebaseAnalytics.logLogin(loginMethod: logLogin);
  }
```

I am looking for solution so I can resolve these.

Comment: You have an `AppAnalytics` class that extends `FirebaseAnalytics`. `FirebaseAnalytics` has a method called `logLogin` which takes an optional named parameter of type `String`. You seem to have overridden this method in your `AppAnalytics` class, but your method takes a parameter of type `Future<Null> Function()`.

Comment: @Ovidiu I have added method which showing this error.

Comment: It looks like the issue is the return type of the function. Your function returns `Future<Null>` although it overrides a function that returns `Future<void>`. `Null` and `void` are technically different.